# SQL - Show all values from the first tabel

Tags: sql

I want to show all values of a column 'nation.nationen_bez' in the tabel 'nation' using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nation.nationen_bez,   
         NVL(SUM (debitor.flimit_deb) OVER (PARTITION BY nation.nationen_bez ORDER BY nation.nationen_bez),0) AS korisceno,   
         NVL(nation_ext.country_limit,0) - NVL(SUM (debitor.flimit_deb) OVER (PARTITION BY nation.nationen_bez ORDER BY nation.nationen_bez),0) AS se_na_voljo,   
         NVL(nation_ext.country_limit,0) AS odobren_limit  
    FROM debitor,   
         nation,   
         nation_ext,   
         firmenstamm,   
         debitorenstamm  
   WHERE ( nation.nationen_kode = debitorenstamm.nationen_kode (+)) and  
         ( nation.nationen_id = nation_ext.nationen_id (+)) and  
         ( debitor.debitoren_id = debitorenstamm.debitoren_id ) and  
         ( debitorenstamm.waehrungs_id = firmenstamm.waehrungs_id ) and  
         ( ( debitor.risiko = 1 ) AND  
         ( debitor.factoringart = 'EF' ))
```

With this query I get only those 'nation.nationen_bez' where exist debitors with debitor.risiko = 1 and
debitor.factoringart = 'EF'. This conditioin is needed for 'NVL(SUM (debitor.flimit_deb) OVER (PARTITION BY nation.nationen_bez ORDER BY nation.nationen_bez),0) AS korisceno', because I want sum only 'flimit_deb' for those debtors that have debitor.risiko = 1 and debitor.factoringart = 'EF' - how can I change this state?

tnx in advance

Comment: `JOIN`. `JOIN`. `JOIN`.  First, your syntax is not valid SQL.  And even in databases that once supported it, it is deprecated.  Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Learn proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: aha ok, thanks. I think I have figured it out

Answer (score 0):

I have used left join, started with nation

```
SELECT DISTINCT nation.nationen_bez, 
SUM (debitor.flimit_deb) OVER (PARTITION BY nation.nationen_bez ORDER BY nation.nationen_bez) AS korisceno,   
nation_ext.country_limit - SUM (debitor.flimit_deb) OVER (PARTITION BY nation.nationen_bez ORDER BY nation.nationen_bez) AS se_na_voljo,   
nation_ext.country_limit AS odobren_limit  
FROM nation
left join debitorenstamm on nation.nationen_kode = debitorenstamm.nationen_kode
left join debitor on debitorenstamm.debitoren_id =  debitor.debitoren_id and debitor.risiko = 1 AND  debitor.factoringart = 'EF' 
left join nation_ext on nation.nationen_id = nation_ext.nationen_id   
left join firmenstamm on  debitorenstamm.waehrungs_id = firmenstamm.waehrungs_id
```